# how to open lightgallery outside the iframe parentWindow

Tags: jquery, iframe, lightgallery

Here is the Html

```
  <div class="card-body" style="display:none" id="card-body" >
            <iframe id="frame{{req['RequestID']}}" class="frameTracking iframe-container" border="0" width="100%"
                    height="100%" data-src="{{ url_for('ViewTracking',reqID = req['RequestID']) }}" src="" onload="frameload(this);" >

            </iframe>
        </div>
```

Here is the html that is on another file

```
 <table class="table lightgallery">
   <td>
 <span class="spnImg">Click here to view <a  data-href="{{img_path2|string}}"  class="lnk_tracking_img">screenshot </a>

                                </span>
</td>
 </table>
```

Below the given function that called on onload

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='global_assets/lightbox/js/lightgallery-all.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='global_assets/lightbox/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function frameload(iframe) {
    // live handler
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
    if (doc.document) { doc = doc.document; };
    $('.lightgallery', doc.body).lightGallery({
              selector : '.spnImg',
              thumbnail : false,
            });
};
</script>
```

Any Help would be appreciated